# Creating unusal CSS3 shape to replace image

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

I am making a game for which all the styling is in css3.

The frame has buttons either side as you can see in the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t9RNe/7/). But currently I have had to make images for the button wrappers as I could not find an elegant solution via css3.

I have made these images for retina screens so that you can not tell the difference between the code and the image but I would love to see a copy of this as a css shape but I am not sure it is possible?

Many thanks for any help

EDIT: This shape has a 4px solid white border either side and a 2px box shadow to the outer side (depending on whether it is the left or right side).

[image: Shape]

HTML

```
<div class="interaction farmyard">

<div class="page-decorations"></div>

<div class="nav">
    <div class="left"><span class="btn prev"></span></div>
    <div class="right"><span class="btn next"></span></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    border: 0 none;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #71AFDF;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
.interaction {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E7F3FF;
    border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
    color: #054B98;
    height: 620px;
    margin: 35px auto 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 930px;
}
.page-decorations {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00576F;
    border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.interaction .nav {
    left: -42px;
    margin-top: -80px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -42px;
    top: 50%;
}
.interaction .nav > div {
    background: url("http://s16.postimg.org/5fp9qny85/button_containers_retina.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / 250px 165px transparent;
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
    height: 165px;
    left: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 125px;
}
.interaction .nav > .right {
    background-position: -122px 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 2px;
}
.interaction .nav > .left > .btn {
    display: block;
    left: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
}
.interaction .nav > .right > .btn {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 21px;
    top: 44px;
}
.btn {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #108FE8;
    border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 3px #0869AF inset, 0 5px 5px rgba(24, 24, 25, 0.17), 0 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) inset;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in 0s;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in 0s;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with css3. or your css would become huge.

Comment: I am willing to add a few more lines of markup to make it possible. after seeing http://www.csstubemap.co.uk/index.html I thought anything was possible!

Comment: You could use SVG images. They are vector-based, re-sizable and a lot smaller.

Comment: I would love to see a css3 example but if that is not possible maybe thats the next best thing? How could i convert it into a svg? I have it in Photoshop and illustrator

Comment: you can export to SVG in illustrator

Comment: Yeah, always go with images for this kind of thing.

Comment: I have tried many different versions of svgs today and they don't match the style 100%

Comment: Show the SVGs you've tried that are closest

Comment: I gave up on SVGs and im not going back lol they are a pain

Comment: +1 because I like your design :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My shabby try :D

http://jsfiddle.net/takrN/5/

Mi goal was to create the shape only with one `<div>`but it's a little tricky! Finally I have the main shape, <strike>but without border and shadow</strike>.

This is pretty funny :D If I had time I'll try to refine later!

UPDATED: I have tried the way Troy Alford reccomends! It looks  more accurate, and finally here's the border with shadow! Not match 100% by the circular border, but... only one `div` mates! Only one `div`! And I Cut-My-Own-Throat! :D

Here's another version with properly border (a bit overlaped), but... with two `<div>`: http://jsfiddle.net/takrN/8/

Comment: Call Goku, the Red Ribbon Army is coming :D btw +1 for the try ;)

Comment: Your shape is fantastic. :) The fix, I think, to add the border/shadow is to make the `:before` element be the circular one, the `:after` element be the right-side rounding, and the `element` itself be the vertical bar. This way you can `z-index` the round element to be in front of the vertical bar, and thereby get a continuous-ish line of border. :) Brilliant code!

Comment: I had to try! Jejejeje. Thanks, for the upvotes and thanks for the idea, @TroyAlford, I think you're totally right! I tried, but I couldn't figure how to make continuous line. I'll try this :)

Comment: Great work Arkana and Chris A, cheers for the answers. I picked this one because of the simple markup and i found it easier to understand. This is a great site :_)

Comment: Thank you, @Parallel2ne! I'm glad to help, also I enjoyed so much doing this :) CSS challenges <3

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pretty solid start: http://jsfiddle.net/carasin/QMaBc/16/

If you really dig into it you'll see it's a combination of creating rectangles and overlaying curved pieces.

I did have to add a bit to the markup:

```
<div class="interaction farmyard">
    <div class="page-decorations"></div>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="left">
                <span class="btn prev"></span>
                <div class="top-right-corner"></div>
                <div class="bottom-right-corner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <span class="btn next"></span>
                <div class="top-left-corner"></div>
                <div class="bottom-left-corner"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS, take a look at the fiddle though.

```
.interaction .nav > div {
    background: #E7F3FF;
    border:5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
    height: 101px;
    width: 101px;
    left: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
.interaction .nav > .right {
    left: auto;
    right: -1px;
}
.interaction .nav > .left > .btn {
    display: block;
    left: 9px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
}
.interaction .nav > .right > .btn {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 9px;
    top: 9px;
}
.btn {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #108FE8;
    border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 3px #0869AF inset, 0 5px 5px rgba(24, 24, 25, 0.17), 0 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) inset;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in 0s;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in 0s;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
}
.btn:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    background:#E7F3FF;
    height:130px;
    width:31px;
    position:absolute;
    left:25px;
    top:-26px;
    z-index:-1;
}
.right .btn:after {
    left:auto;
    right:25px;
}
.top-right-corner {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 37px;
    background: #00576F;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 29px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -38px;
    right: 25px;
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}
.top-right-corner:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #00576F;
    border-radius: 95px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: -27px;
}
.bottom-right-corner {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 37px;
    background: #00576F;
    border-radius: 29px 0 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -36px;
    right: 25px;
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}
.bottom-right-corner:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #00576F;
    border-radius: 95px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    right: -29px;
}
.top-left-corner {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 37px;
    background: #00576F;
    border-radius: 0 0 29px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -38px;
    left: 25px;
    border-right: 4px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}    
.top-left-corner:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #00576F;
    border-radius: 95px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -27px;
}
.bottom-left-corner {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 37px;
    background: #00576F;
    border-radius: 0 29px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -36px;
    left: 25px;
    border-right: 4px solid #fff;
    border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}
.bottom-left-corner:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #00576F;
    border-radius: 95px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: -29px;
}
```

Comment: You can try editing the "corner" div's width and then there :before elements a bit to see if you can get a gentler curve.

Comment: Brilliant and beautiful. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea if this would be helpful but have you considered converting your image to canvas?  Would this fulfill your requirements in any way?

There's some good info on this [here](http://davidwalsh.name/convert-canvas-image) if your ok with using javascript to accomplish this.

That being said [not all browsers / devices support canvas drawing](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-canvas)

I got stuck with only being able to use css3D transforms for a cross device / cross platform app with a 3D UI requirement and tried to fart around with SVG.  It was pretty painful.

Comment: Thanks foe an answer, it is good to know that you can do that but it isnt right for this scenario. Cheers